# The number of integer solutions of an equality

Tags: inequality

I should find the number of integer solutions of: $$(2x+1)^3-8x(-x-2)^2>(x+1)^2.$$
How to approach the problem? I tried to simplify it, but it doesn’t look good. Should I continue this way?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you expand everything and factor the polynomial (possibly cubic or lower degree)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand out the powers, and subtract right side from left side.  You'll get a quadratic that factors nicely...